# Solving Integration problem, area of a curve?

Tags: integration, algebraic-curves, area

I am working my way through a self study book of scientific and engineering principles. Although it covers a pretty broad range of subjects, there are obviously a few maths related topics in it as well. One of the topics which I find myself struggling with is the integration problems (well, I assume they are integration problems?)

There are many questions on working out the area of the curve, for example:

What area lies between the curve $y=x^3+2x$, the x axis, the y axis and the line $x=4$?

Its not really clear from the notes how you go about solving the examples like this, can anyone offer any help with it?

Comment: Always draw a picture. Are you comfortable with the integral representing the "signed" area between the graph and the $x$ axis?

Comment: By definition, you are solving $\int_0^4 (x^3+2x) dx$

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

Area bounded by the curve $y=x^3+2x$, x-axis, y-axis & the line $x=4$ is $$=\int_{x=0}^{x=4}ydx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{4}(x^3+2x)dx$$
$$=\left[\frac{x^4}{4}+2\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{4}$$
$$=\left[\frac{x^4}{4}+x^2\right]_{0}^{4}$$
$$=\left[\frac{(4)^4}{4}+(4)^2-0\right]$$
$$=64-16=\color{red}{48}$$

Answer (score 0):

A small graphing of the above indicated region shows that your domain is [image]
(Sorry the three should be 4 in the graph). 
As it can be seen from this graph that x varies between 0 and 4, while y is bounded  between $y=0$ and the graph  $y=x^3+2x$.
Then to find the are of the domain bounded between $y=x^3+2x$, $x=4$  , x-axis, and y axis, you may  follow this integration 
$$ \int_{0}^4 \int_{0}^{x^3+2x} 1 dy dx $$